# GWT SuggestBox: How do I force the SuggestBox to select the first item in the suggestion list?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a textbox and one suggestbox. I attach a value change and key up handler to the text box such that whatever the user types (or pastes) into the text box is echo-ed inside the suggestbox. I can get the suggestbox to display the suggestion list by calling showSuggestionList on each value change and key up event.

Now, how do I get the suggestbox to automatically choose the first item in the suggestion list?

One of the methods I tried is to programatically simulate key presses,  i.e

```
suggestBox.setFocus(true);
NativeEvent enterEvent = Document.get().createKeyPressEvent(false, false, false,   false, KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER);
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(enterEvent, suggestBox);
textBox.setFocus(true);
```

This doesn't work at all. The enter key isn't simulated. Another possible solution is to extend SuggestionBox.SuggestionDisplay, but I'm not too sure how to that. Any pointers appreciated.

Update: I'm still working on this and trying various methods.

Here, I tried to implement my own SuggestionDisplay by subclassing DefaultSuggestionDisplay and overriding getCurrentSelection() to make accessible from my class. This doesn't work either. Null is returned.

```
    private class CustomSuggestionDisplay extends DefaultSuggestionDisplay {
    @Override
    protected Suggestion getCurrentSelection() {
        return super.getCurrentSelection();
    }
}

    suggestBox.setAutoSelectEnabled(true);

    textBox.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            suggestBox.setValue(textBox.getText(), true);
            suggestBox.showSuggestionList();
            if (suggestBox.isSuggestionListShowing()) {
                String s = ((CustomSuggestionDisplay) suggestBox.getSuggestionDisplay()).getCurrentSelection().getDisplayString();
                Window.alert(s);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here, I tried to attach a value change handler to the SuggestBox, and casting the event type to SuggestOracle.Suggestion. Again, null is returned.

```
suggestBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
            String s = ((SuggestOracle.Suggestion) event).getDisplayString();
            Window.alert(s);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `suggesBox.setAutoSelectEnabled(true)`

[Here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html) more info about the SuggestBox of GWT:

Comment: setAutoSelectEnabled is true by default. what it does is that as the user types in the suggestbox, and presses enter, the first item is selected. if set to false, nothing happens when you press enter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using addSelectionHandler in conjunction with setAutoSelectEnabled to receive an event whenever a suggestion is selected.  You could also have your Oracle send a message when it suggests something, or your Display send a message when it displays a list:

```
public class AutomaticallySelectingSuggestionDisplay extends SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay {
    @Override
    protected void showSuggestions(SuggestBox box, Collection<? extends SuggestOracle.Suggestion> suggestions, boolean isDisplayHtml, boolean isAutoSelectEnabled, SuggestBox.SuggestionCallback callback) {
        super.showSuggestions(box, suggestions, isDisplayHtml, isAutoSelectEnabled, callback);
        fireValueChangeEventWithFirstSuggestion(suggestions);
    }
}
```

This idea feels a little muddled to me, so I hope you can find a solution just using event handlers.

Comment: hi, thanks for your input, but I have no idea how to implement the fireValueChangeEventWithFirstSuggestion(suggestions) method. can you elaborate? Another method, as you mentioned is to fire a selection event through a value change handler inside the suggest box. I'm trying this method too, but to no avail.